# Face detection and image preview drawing

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, graphics, directshow

I'm developing application that uses DirectShow combined with C++.
Its main goal is to capture users' faces.
I have reached the phase when I capture a image from my webcam. 
The problem is I need an intelligent render. In fact, I need that render to be able to detect a face inside a rectangle. 
I'm wondring if there is a filter that I can use for this purpose, 
or if I need to create my own custmized filter. 
If so enlighten my mind.
It would look like this: 
[image]

---

**I need to understand how I can draw a recangle in my render in the first place. Because otherwise, even if I know the algorithm, I will not be able to  apply it. This is my main goal now.**

I have some idea but I don't know if they are correct. I think I need to grab each frame separately and apply some modification in some pixels, like what's drawn in the live render.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

Quick look inside and I found [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection/).

Making your own "filter" that works well is no easy job.

Comment: yes interesting but unfortunately i' have the obligation to use directshow (microsoft ) @@

Comment: This should not hinder you to additionally use the OpenCV library. Btw - the Haarlike-methods in OpenCV build exactly on the class of algorithms I mentioned in my answer. So I think taking OpenCV with these (complicated!) algorithms ready to go and readily parameterized (!!! this is a LOT of work!!) is definitely a good idea in your case.

Comment: Surely you can just use DirectShow to connect to the webcam, and then pass the frames over to OpenCV to run the image processing side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about automatic detection of *where* there is something like a human face in the shot you have taken with the webcam? In this case object detection algorithms like [Viola-Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) might be interesting for you.

Comment: the problem is not in  the algorithms the problem is how to draw a recangle in this render after that i can apply this algo

Comment: So the question is only about how to draw a rectangle with DirectShow?

Comment: Do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115399/how-to-draw-on-an-unfilled-box-on-a-video-stream-using-the-mouse or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377901/drawing-a-rectangle-or-line-or-bitmap-on-the-camera-preview-stream-net-comp help?

Answer (score 0):

If a commercial package is an option, you can use the [Montivision Filter SDK](http://www.montivision.com/en/products/surveillance/) which includes filters that should do the job out of the box. They offer a free eval which is perfect for experimentation.